# jQuery click does not show spinner on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where user can upload files. if the has selected the file and he clicks on the verify button I want to hide the verify emails text and show a spinner instead. but after clicking on the button it doesn't show the spinner. It showed the loader if I remove the if condition. but I want the spinner only to show the file is selected and the user clicks on the verify button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#emailList').val()) {
    $("#emailListVerify").click(function() {
      $("#verifyEmailsLoading").show();
      $("#verifyEmailsText").hide();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="email_verify.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="upload-container" id="upload_btn">
    <input type="file" name="email_list" id="emailList" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="email-list-verify-submit" id="emailListVerify" class="btn btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light">
    <span id="verifyEmailsLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span id="verifyEmailsText">Verify Emails</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: The main issue that the `if` needs to go ***inside*** the click handler. *However*, what you're trying to do is largely pointless. This is because clicking the button causes the form to be submit which in turn unloads the current page, which means no further amendments can be made to the DOM. Having a spinner at that point is redundant (unless you're sending the data via AJAX) as the page will redirect momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Dont wrap event listeners in if statements, rather do the check inside
  the event handler.
- I think the inline style 'display:none' is overriding the toggle
- In the event handler, return false to prevent the page from reloading
  and add your logic above the return

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#verifyEmailsLoading").hide();
  $("#emailListVerify").click(function() {
   if ($('#emailList').val()) {
      $("#verifyEmailsLoading").show();
      $("#verifyEmailsText").hide();
      return false;
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="email_verify.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="upload-container" id="upload_btn">
    <input type="file" name="email_list" id="emailList" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="email-list-verify-submit" id="emailListVerify" class="btn btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light">
    <span id="verifyEmailsLoading" role="status">Loading</span>
    <span id="verifyEmailsText">Verify Emails</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: With this, the form doesn't submit and reload the loader shows again.

Comment: @lachiweb, yes see point number three and the comment on your question. If you just want to submit the form, all your code is irrelevant. If you want a spinner showing and hiding, you have to implement an ajax post in the event handler